# My Business API: "Provided service type ID is not among those supported by the business's categories."

Tags: php, google-api, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I am trying to patch a location with some new service types and I am using `validateOnly` set to `true`.

But the response I am getting is: `"Provided service type ID is not among those supported by the business's categories."`

I have been testing with different `serviceId` types such as:

```
gcid:parking_garage
gcid:parking_lot
gcid:parking_lot_for_bicycles
gcid:parking_lot_for_motorcycle
```

but to no avail.

Full error message is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "service_items[0].structured_service_item.service_type_id",
            "description": "Provided service type ID is not among those supported by the business's categories."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am using the official PHP API client + service APIs as provided here:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services

Official API reference:

- https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/locations/patch?hl=en
- https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/services?hl=en

Any tips?

Comment: What serviceId are you using?

Comment: It's mentioned above in the question.

Comment: Those are location categories, not services

Comment: I tried free form as well with categories mentioned: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations#freeformserviceitem
I also tried structured type: _The serviceTypeId field is a Google provided unique ID that can be found in ServiceType. This information is provided by categories.batchGet rpc service._
So it seems that categories and service IDs are the same, see: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/categories/batchGet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood that documentation. The endpoint to get the categories will show you the available serviceIds per category if you request the FULL CategoryView (https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/CategoryView).

To inspect available services for the given categories, a less cumbersome approach is to add them to a test location via the GBP UI and then execute a location get request and readMask set to serviceItems to inspect what the serviceItems array looks like for that location.

Added by the OP:
For anyone wondering about `location` object difference between `location->categories->primaryCategory->serviceTypes` (also for `->additionalCategories[x]`) and `location->serviceItems` some info to clarify:

- `location->categories->primaryCategory->serviceTypes` seems to be `readonly`

  - and you just need to patch `location->categories->primaryCategory` (`->additionalCategories[x]`), format is similar to `categories/gcid:wellness_center`
- **`location->serviceItems` are meant to be updated (patched) directly**

  - format is similar to `job_type_id:swimming` for `structuredServiceItem`
  - and any string for `freeFormServiceItem`.

Comment: So actually, when using `batchGet` or `list` (same when using `FULL`) I am still just getting `moreHoursTypes` and not `servicesTypes` and those former are pretty useless/generic. From your response it is still not clear how to change/update/patch the categories business is associated with. Please, update the response this way and I will accept it.

Comment: Update: So apparently some `category IDs` do not have any `service IDs` associated. So now I have found some that work. Thanks for the pointer.